# no models on fetch collection.fetch in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My collection.fetch doesn't work and doesn't get the models to be rendered.
I have this on my router.js

```
itemcollection = new ItemCollection();
        itemcollection.fetch();
        ItemListView.render();
        CartListView.render();
    }
```

my itemcollection.js

```
define([
'underscore',
'backbone',
'model/item_model'
  ],function(_, Backbone, Item){
var ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,
    url: 'http://posbeta.interprisesolutions.com/POSMobileConnector/Product/loaditembycategory/Event Materials',
    parse: function(response) {
    return response.Items;
  }
});
return ItemCollection;
});
```

my view:

```
initialize: function(){
  ItemCollection.bind("reset", this.render );
},
render: function(){
  var data = {
    items: itemcollection.models
  }
  var compiledTemplate = _.template( ItemListTemplate , data);
  $("#itemContainer").html( compiledTemplate );

},
```

The funny thing is when i debug it using firebug it renders properly when i remove the breakpoint it doesn't display anything. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that `fetch` is asynchronous - it returns immediately, before the data has been loaded.

You could try something like:

```
itemcollection = new ItemCollection();
itemcollection.fetch({
  success: function () {
    ItemListView.render();
    CartListView.render();
  }
});
```

Alternatively, you could listen on the collection's `reset` event.

Comment: i have the reset though but its not working. ItemCollection.bind("reset", this.render );

Comment: You may need to bind `this`: `ItemCollection.on('reset', this.render, this);`

Comment: i would like to ask just for clarification. if i already instantiated ItemCollection on itemlist view do i need to instantiate it again if i want to use it on another view?

Comment: It's a good question, and I don't think there is (or can be) a definitive answer. You could fetch the collection from each view, or you could store it in a central place and fetch it once. It depends on the usage patterns of your application and the size of your collections.

Example: in an application I'm writing, there is very little total data for a single logged-in user, so I hold it in a central place, and only load it once (on demand).

Counter-example: if I were writing an online shop, I'd probably load reviews for each product on-demand in each view, and not store them centrally.

Comment: actually i'm not fetching all the data. In the application i'm writing i'm fetching the items and passing the clicked item on a cart collection. my problem now is i can add but it doesn't reflect or show.

Answer (score 0):

The url has a space in it :

.../Event   Materials',

Try removing it or encoding it with `%20`

Comment: hmm. thank you but it worked before though. Because before i was returning an instantiated collection. "return new ItemCollection" since some say its a bad practice so i removed it.